# How to map tibble elements to ggplot2 aesthetics?

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I have the following dataset

```
map(.x = list(small = 3, medium = 10, large  = 100) , 
      .f = ~ sample(rnorm(1000), .x, replace = T)) %>% 
      tibble(sample = ., mean = map_dbl(., mean)) 

# A tibble: 3 x 2
       sample       mean
       <list>      <dbl>
1   <dbl [3]> 0.61473548
2  <dbl [10]> 0.17278357
3 <dbl [100]> 0.04156308
```

I am trying to functionally create 1 histogram in ggplot2 for each record in the column `sample`. I would like to display the plots in the same grid, thus I thought I could somehow use `facet_wrap()` but I am not sure how to map aesthetics to lists.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
map(.x = list(small = 3, medium = 10, large  = 100) , 
          .f = ~ sample(rnorm(1000), .x, replace = T)) %>% 
          tibble(sample = ., mean = map_dbl(., mean)) %>% 
   ggplot2::ggplot(data = .) + geom_histogram(mapping = aes(sample)) + facet_wrap(~ sample)
```

The output I expect is 3 histograms with 3, 10 and 100 observations respectively.

I wonder if a possible solution my involve splitting `sample` in two columns: one with all the values, another indicating the distribution size that each value belongs to. This is probably more compliant with the ggplot2 logic, but I am not sure how to expand the tibble accordingly.

ps: I am not sure how to phrase the question any suggestions is welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `tidyr::unnest`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

## generate data
set.seed(123)
dtf <- map(.x = list(small = 3, medium = 10, large  = 100),
           .f = ~ sample(rnorm(1000), .x, replace = T)) %>%
    tibble(sample = ., mean = map_dbl(., mean))

## plot
dtf %>%
    mutate(group = names(sample)) %>%  # or: group = lengths(sample)
    unnest(sample) %>%
    ggplot(data = .) +
    geom_histogram(mapping = aes(sample)) +
    facet_wrap(~ group)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The list structure is giving you problems. Try this:

```
    tibble(id = rep(c("small", "medium", "large"), c(3,10,100)),
       samples = sample(rnorm(1000), 113, replace = T)) %>%
ggplot2::ggplot(data = .) + 
    geom_histogram(mapping = aes(samples)) + facet_wrap(~ id)
```

Comment: +1 cause this is practically very close to what I am doing, but it is not very generalizable. For instance with `replace = F` it is impossible for the same value to be in two distinct plots. Instead, I might wanna have `replace=F` within the same plot, but not between plots.

Comment: Hm, I see. You can call sample more than once and concatenate the results. `dist <- rnorm(1000); samples <- c(sample(dist,3), sample(dist,10), sample(dist,100));`